# how to replace a values in list if same value occurred eg : [1,0,1,0,1,1] so last value should be '0'

Tags: python, list

```
def list(A):
head=0
tail=1
new_list=[]
for i in A:
    if i==1:
        new_list.append(i)
    if i==1:
        new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

A=ast.literal_eval(input())
list(A)

> I have a list with value [1,0,1,0,1,1] so now I want replaces a value '0' where 1,1 is there
> output: [1,0,1,0,1,0] how can get this in python. Please help me

Comment: Don't name your function `list`, since that will mask the builtin `list`.

Comment: Is it possible to have consecutive `0`s in the expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a comparison between the list and the shifted list inside a list comprehension (and keep the fist element as is):

```
def decouple(a_list):
    return [a_list[0]] + \
        [(x != x_shifted) * x for x, x_shifted in zip(a_list[1:], a_list[:-1])]

decouple([1,0,1,0,1,1])
# > [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this simple program.

```
def replacement (l):
    l1 = l
    for i in range(len(l1)-1):
        if l1[i]==0 and l1[i+1]==0:
            l1[i+1]=1
        elif l1[i]==1 and l1[i+1]==1:
            l1[i+1]=0
    return l1
print(replacement ([1,0,1,0,11])


#== Output [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
#== same output with [1,0,0,0,1,1]
```